# Getting text box names and text boxes inline

Tags: html, alignment, html-table, element, inline

Following is my code that I have used to make a html form! Currently the text box names and text boxes are one after the other.
For example: NIC and its text box are not inline.

If I use two `<td>` tags for a pair of elements though they become inline they are far apart! How can I correct this issue?

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <style>input.textfill {
            float: right;
        }</style>
        </head>

         <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
            <form id=orders name="orders" action="orders_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  onsubmit="return Validate(this);">

                <table align="Center"  >

                   <tr><td height="40"><br>
                <div class="headingbox" id="hBoxNIC" > National ID  </div>
                <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="920290505v" maxlength="13" name=NIC required   autofocus  />
                       </div>

                </td></tr>
                <tr><td height=50 ><div class="headingboxs">Pick up</div>
                    <input   type=radio name=DP  required value="Pickup">

    <div style="  float: right;"><div class="headingboxs">
        Delivery</div>
                        <input  class="textfill" type=radio name=DP required value="Delivery" onmouseup="textbox(this)" /></div><br><br></td></tr>


    <tr><td height="50"><div class="headingbox" >Expected Time </div>
                <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                <input type="time" id=time  autofocus name=DPTime    onfocusout="hid('timeerror2');" onfocus="show('timeerror2');"min="09:00:00" max="22:00:00" /><br>
                </div>

                   <div class="poperror" id="timeerror2"> Pharmacy is opened from 9AM to 10PM  </div>
        <script>
    var input =  document.getElementById('time');
    function validateTime (element) {

    var minTime = element.min;
    var maxTime = element.max
    var value = element.value + ':00'

    if(minTime > value || value > maxTime) {
    console.log("Time is outside of min/max.");
    }

    }       

    </script>  

                    </td></tr>


    <tr><td height="50"><div class="headingbox" id="hBoxPN"> Phone Number </div>
                <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">

                <input type="text" maxlength=10;  autofocus name=Tele /><br>
                </div>
                <div class="error" id="phoneerror" > error occured </div><br></td></tr>





                <tr><td height="50"><div class="headingbox" id="hBoxEM"> E-mail </div>
                <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                <input type="text"  autofocus name=Email placeholder="xxx@gmail.com"    /><br>
                </div>
                <div class="error" id="emailerror" > error occured </div><br>

                    </td></tr>
                             <tr>
                        <td height="50" width=330><br><div class="headingbox"> Prescription Copy-1</div> <div id="kids">

    <input id="uploadFile" class="disableInputField" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />


    <label class="fileUpload">
        <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name=Image1 />
        <span class="uploadBtn">Upload</span>
    </label>



            <input type="button" id="add" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />

          </div></td></tr>
                    <script>
                    document.getElementById("uploadBtn" ).onchange = function()  {
                document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
            };
        </script>


            </div></td></tr>

                <tr><td colspan=5 align=center>
                    <input class="button" type=submit name=submit value=Place >
                    <input class="button" type=reset name=reset value=Cancel> </td></tr>
                </table>

                  </form>



        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k9spo7ru/) is what you are looking for. I basically replaced all the `div` tags with `span` tags. A span element will naturally be in-line while divs will try to move down to the next line.

```js
            var input = document.getElementById('time');

            function validateTime(element) {

              var minTime = element.min;
              var maxTime = element.max
              var value = element.value + ':00'

              if (minTime > value || value > maxTime) {
                console.log("Time is outside of min/max.");
              }

            }

            document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function() {
              document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
            };
```

```css
input.textfill {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
  <form id=orders name="orders" action="orders_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
    <table align="">
      <tr>
        <td height="40">
          <br>
          <span class="headingbox" id="hBoxNIC"> National ID </span>
          <span style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="920290505v" maxlength="13" name=NIC required autofocus />
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height=50>
          <span class="headingboxs">Pick up</span>
          <input type=radio name=DP required value="Pickup">
          <span style="  float: right;">
            <span class="headingboxs">
              Delivery</span>
          <input class="textfill" type=radio name=DP required value="Delivery" onmouseup="textbox(this)" />
          </span>
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50">
          <span class="headingbox">Expected Time </span>
          <span style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <input type="time" id=time autofocus name=DPTime onfocusout="hid('timeerror2');" onfocus="show('timeerror2');" min="09:00:00" max="22:00:00" />
            <br>
          </span>
          <span class="poperror" id="timeerror2"> Pharmacy is opened from 9AM to 10PM </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50">
          <span class="headingbox" id="hBoxPN"> Phone Number </span>
          <span style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <input type="text" maxlength=10; autofocus name=Tele />
            <br>
          </span>
          <span class="error" id="phoneerror"> error occured </span>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50">
          <span class="headingbox" id="hBoxEM"> E-mail </span>
          <span style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <input type="text" autofocus name=Email placeholder="xxx@gmail.com" />
            <br>
          </span>
          <span class="error" id="emailerror"> error occured </span>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50" width=330>
          <br>
          <span class="headingbox"> Prescription Copy-1</span>
          <span id="kids">
            <input id="uploadFile" class="disableInputField" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
            <label class="fileUpload">
              <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name=Image1 />
              <span class="uploadBtn">Upload</span>
          </label>
          <input type="button" id="add" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=5 align=center>
          <input class="button" type=submit name=submit value=Place>
          <input class="button" type=reset name=reset value=Cancel>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanx but i wont them to be aligned with the alle the text boxes aligned below each other! your one they are bit crucked

Comment: you want them all aligned to left edge below their desc like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k9spo7ru/1/)?

Comment: It was also intially like that! i want it inline and close together,i.e https://jsfiddle.net/k9spo7ru/ along with the elements in order! not one after the other! like name of the text box and the text box on the same line! and the text box in the next line being just below the text box of the previous line! i meant the text box of email being directly below that of  phone number! i.e they both being aligned vertically!